# C# Database Connectivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

Consider the following code segment, I get the following error

Exception:

```
'could not find installable ISAM'.
```

My code is:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Login.accdb;Persist Security Infor=false";
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It still gives the error. Could it be my environment or where I am running the program (Domain)?

Comment: Hi! I managed to get the connection. What I did to achieve this is, I copied my database into the bin\Debug folder of my project and I changed the data source in my code to where it is located.